# Is it safe to output temporary AWS credentials into a <script> tag from PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-php-sdk

I jumped into working on an application built by another developer, and the method that was used to connect to the AWS JavaScript SDK was to output temporary credentials into a script tag. The code essentially looks something like this in the `index.php` file:

```
<?php

$stsclient = StsClient::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'thekey',
        'secret' => 'thesecret'
    )
));

$session = $stsclient->getSessionToken([
  'DurationSeconds' => 129600
]);

$temp_creds = $session->get('Credentials');

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    AWS.config.update({
      accessKeyId : '<?php echo $temp_creds['AccessKeyId']; ?>',
      secretAccessKey : '<?php echo $temp_creds['SecretAccessKey']; ?>',
      sessionToken: '<?php echo $temp_creds['SessionToken']; ?>'
    });
    AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';
</script>
```

I know this should be done with the profile option and a `~/.aws/credentials` file so it's not committed to a public repo, which I will eventually do.

However, is outputting temporary credentials onto the page that change on every page visit secure?

Comment: STS only generates a temporary token so that the credentials do not work anymore after a specific time. However, the question of safety is more about what a user can do with those credentials, you have to make absolutely sure that the user can only do what he is supposed to do with these (i.e. by configuring IAM the exactly correct way)

Comment: The access keys have the appropriate scoped permission of being able to upload documents to s3. The session duration is long: 129600 seconds. Couldn't someone visit the page and open the page source and do something malicious with the temporary creds and upload a bunch of stuff if they wanted?

Comment: This looks like a pretty standard implementation. STS only gives you temporary, limited scope credentials for already authenticated users (either via IAM or federation). If the duration of the credentials is an issue for your use case, you can always shorten the duration. Yes, a malicious user could technically open the page, get the credentials, and upload a bunch of stuff... You should be addressing that separately. Uploads should be quarantined, checked for MIME type, viruses, rate limit etc, and then sent to the final storage location; there are a few patterns for this.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Noted on the session duration. When you say "there are a few patterns for this", do you have some examples? Much appreciated!

Comment: "Couldn't someone visit the page and open the page source and do something malicious with the temporary creds and upload a bunch of stuff if they wanted?" -> Yes!